# Inside a trigger, insert n rows from the original table into a new table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, triggers

I have the following table:

```
==OFFICES==
OFFICE INTEGER NOT NULL,
CITY VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
REGION VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
DIR INTEGER,
OBJECTIVE MONEY,
SALES MONEY
```

I have to define a trigger named TRIGGER_EX3. Whenever a new row is inserted into OFFICES, it stores into a table named TCONTROL_OFFICES the following values:

```
==TCONTROL_OFFICES==
INSERTION_DATE DATETIME, --The day the office was inserted
OPERATION VARCHAR(15), --The name of the operation (inserted)
OFFICE INTEGER, --The id of the office (The value of OFFICE in OFFICES)
THE_USER VARCHAR(30) --Name of the user
```

My idea was to use a while loop (or for loop) to insert the first row of INSERTED into TCONTROL_OFFICES and then delete that same row from INSERTED and repeat until INSERTED was empty. However, it seems I can't modify INSERTED. Regardless, it still seemed like a clumsy approach. Is there any better way of doing this?

This is what I have so far:

```
USE EMPLOYEES
GO
IF(OBJECT_ID ('TRIGGER_EX3', 'TR') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
    DROP TRIGGER TRIGGER_EX3;
END
GO
CREATE TRIGGER TRIGGER_EX3 ON OFFICES
AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    --CHECK IF THE TABLE EXISTS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT * 
        FROM SYS.TABLES
        WHERE NAME = 'TCONTROL_OFFICES') --IT DOES
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'IT EXISTS';
    END
    ELSE --IT DOESNT
    BEGIN
        CREATE TABLE TCONTROL_OFFICES
        (INSERTION_DATE DATETIME,
        OPERATION VARCHAR(15),
        OFFICE INTEGER,
        THE_USER VARCHAR(30));
    END

    WHILE((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM INSERTED) > 0)
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO TCONTROL_OFFICES
        VALUES(GETDATE(), 'INSERT', (SELECT OFFICE FROM INSERTED), SUSER_SNAME())

        DELETE TOP (1) FROM INSERTED
    END
END
```

Keep in mind that the insertion can be of 3 rows but it may also be of 100+ so I cannot write 1 by 1 every row I want to insert.

Comment: Why do you need to check `TCONTROL_OFFICES` exists? Why wouldn't it?

Comment: Aside: When checking for the existence of one or more rows it is more efficient to use [`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx) rather than getting an exact [`COUNT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175997.aspx) and then just checking if it is greater than zero.

Comment: Aside:  The "current user" can be a slippery concept. If impersonation is being used then [`Original_Login`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/original-login-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) might, or might not, be a better choice. If the application, e.g. a website, uses a single database login for all application users then you'll need another method to identify the application user, e.g. explicitly setting a value in [`Session_Context`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/session-context-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on each connection.

Comment: I need to check if it exists mostly because the task requires me to do so. But it also may be the case that it's the first time this trigger happens, so the table doesnt exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do an `INSERT ... SELECT`. You don't need any loop at all.

```
INSERT INTO tcontrol_offices
            (insertion_date,
             operation,
             office,
             the_user)
            SELECT getdate(),
                   'INSERT',
                   office,
                   suser_sname()
                   FROM inserted;
```